# Mount Qnap drive in Debian

Tags: hard-drive, debian, hard-drive-recovery, mdadm, qnap

So I have a HDD drive ejected from Qnap (I do not longer have it) and I wanted to mount it in home made server with OMV on Debian machine. There is no way I can do that, it cannot be mounted. I tried with different approach and found mdadm. But it has some issues I cannot fix.

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 7.28 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD80PUZX-64N
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 569E0FE3-E299-4149-B9C7-5AA7EDD455CC

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 15628053134 15628051087  7.3T Linux filesystem
```

and then:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdb1
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 has no superblock - assembly aborted
```

```
sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
```

Any chance to get it back?

Comment: Does [this procedure](https://alex3305.github.io/home-assistant-docs/homelab/qnap-linux-mount/) work for you ?

Comment: No, it does not...

Comment: Are you sure that the disk wasn't damaged? D